# Is Flashpoint the reason for Caitlin Snow's powers in the TV series Flash?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, arrowverse, the-flash

In the TV series The Flash Season 4 episode 22, they show that Killer Frost was there within Caitlin Snow since childhood. That means Killer Frost did not get her powers because of the particle accelerator explosion and the powers were naturally inside her, but before flashpoint there were no signs of Killer Frost in Caitlin.

Is Flashpoint the reason for Killer Frost to emerge more strongly or was she going to come out sooner or later irrespective of the flashpoint?

Comment: That show is messed up so bad, and getting more and more messed up

Answer (score 2):

**Almost certainly not**

The "birth" of Killer Frost is explained in the fifth season episode "Icicle cometh" where

> Caitlin reunites with her father.

**Warning ! Unmarked spoiler ahead**

In that episode, we learn that Thomas Snow tried to find a cure to his ALS. Unfortunately, the cure had some side effects and he had to be locked in his lab for years, and the world was lead to believe he was dead.

When a young Caitlin was diagnosed as potentially developing ALS too at a later age, he performed cryogenic experiments on his daughter. Her DNA mutated and she developed the Killer Frost personality as a side effect.

She repressed the memory of Killer Frost for many years but her split personality emerged again during Season 3.

*Note*: since the timeline of the Seasons 1 and 2, and the timeline after Eobard Thawne reversed Flashpoint are not exactly the same, we cannot be completely sure that Flashpoint is not involved in the process. But we know that there was a Killer Frost on Earth-2 in the timeline before Flashpoint and her family history (dead father and distant mother) is similar on that Earth.

Answer (score 0):

> In the Flashpoint timeline, Caitlin is not a scientist but is a doctor
>   who is unwillingly brought into Ramon Industries by Barry to help him
>   restore the timeline. Following Barry's attempt to restore the
>   timeline, Caitlin is once again a scientist at S.T.A.R. Labs, but also
>   seemingly from changing time again she is also a meta-human with
>   abilities similar to her Earth Two doppelgänger, who she is afraid of
>   becoming like. However, it's also implied that she could have been
>   affected prior to Flashpoint. After being taken over by her rising
>   anger while using her meta-human powers, losing control of her
>   emotions, she briefly started going by her doppelgänger's name Killer
>   Frost.

from [this](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Caitlin_Snow)

Comment: Whilst the link may answer the question it is also best to explain in your own words how it answers the question.